# Open source equivalent to CRXDE Lite for Jackrabbit

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, sling, crx

Is there an open source equivalent to Adobe/Day's CRXDE Lite that can be used with the Sling Launchpad?

Comment: Questions on tools are not supposed to be asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . There is a eclipse plugin for sling http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sling-ide-tooling

Comment: Not fully CRXDE Lite, but there is an onging development of a JCRBrowser: http://adapt.to/2014/en/schedule/the-sling-jcrbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

dealing with Day (now Adobe) CRX and working with Sling for quite sometimes, I decided to create one with minimal functions.  It doesn't replace the whole CRXDE but hopefully it's enough to get you started.  The project is still young and I'm actively improving it.  Eventually I would like to contribute this to Sling as an alternative explorer.

https://github.com/cmseifu/sling-browser